# Yii2: Replace querystring parameter with value using urlManager

Tags: yii2

I have a rule in urlManager

```
    'rules' => [
        'products/<whatever:[-_0-9a-zA-Z]+>' => 'products/show',
    ],
```

and I have controller Products with actionShow()

```
public function actionShow($name)
{
    var_dump($name);
    echo 'actionShow is work';
}
```

But a have an Error: Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: name

How to transfer a product's $name to the controller, or how it can be obtained from the URL in the controller?

Comment: How do you call your controller?

Comment: added an answer for you see if that helps you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`CORRECT and COMPLETE`** answer is that you have to use the `rule` like below.

```
'rules' => [
        'products/<name:[\-\w]+>' => 'products/show',
],
```

then in your products controller you don't need to pass `$name` in the parameter anymore that is why we defined in the rule and you have to use the 
`Yii::$app->request->queryParams['name'];` or `Yii::$app->request->get('name')` to get the name of the product, your action will look like below

```
public function actionShow()
{
   echo Yii::$app->request->get('name');
}
```

after doing all the settings above open brower and type

**`http://yourdomain.com/products/some-product`**

and it will show you

**`some-product`**

When you have to create a link to that page lets say in menu you have under `products` all products listed and you have to create a link to detail page for all of them i.e `actionShow` you would do it like below.

```
<?=Html::a($model->name, 
    Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl([
        'products/show',
        'name'=>$model->slug
    ])
  );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should specify the name of your variable in the rule. You are calling it `whatever`, change it to `name`:

```
'rules' => [
        'products/<name:[-_0-9a-zA-Z]+>' => 'products/show',
    ],
```

Comment: Nearly. But in this case I would be obliged to write in the URL: `products/namesamsung450z`

Comment: nopes you are the wrong @yiier, although gmc is right but he hasnt given the complete answer.